# Convert a TrueType font to a Game Boy tileset

Tags: c, converting, freetype

I recently had a need to convert a TrueType font to a Game Boy tileset, so I wrote a program to do it.

This correctly aligns the characters on an 8x8 plane and outputs in the form of RGBDS-style GBZ80 assembly.

Needs the FreeType library installed; use the Makefile (or copy the commands) to compile it.

`drawtile.c`:

```
/*
 * Copyright © 2020 James Larrowe
 *
 * This file is part of ttf2gb.
 *
 * ttf2gb is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * ttf2gb is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with ttf2gb.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 */

#include "ttf2gb.h"

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H /* FT_FaceRec, FT_GlyphSlotRec */
#include FT_IMAGE_H /* FT_BBox, FT_Bitmap, FT_UShort, FT_Int */

/* assumes horizontal font */

void draw_tile(const FT_FaceRec *face)
{
    FT_Int i, j;
    FT_BBox box = face->bbox;
    const FT_GlyphSlotRec *glyph = face->glyph;
    const FT_Bitmap *bitmap = &glyph->bitmap;
    const FT_UShort hEM = face->units_per_EM / bitmap->width;
    const FT_UShort vEM = face->units_per_EM / bitmap->rows;

    box.xMin /= hEM;
    box.xMax /= hEM;
    box.yMin /= vEM;
    box.yMax /= vEM;

#ifndef NDEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "rows:%u, width:%u\n", bitmap->rows, bitmap->width);
    fprintf(stderr, "top:%u, left:%u\n", glyph->bitmap_top, glyph->bitmap_left);
    fprintf(stderr, "horizontal units per EM:%hu, vertical:%hu\n", hEM, vEM);
    fprintf(stderr, "xmin:%ld, xmax:%ld\n", box.xMin, box.xMax);
    fprintf(stderr, "ymin:%ld, ymax:%ld\n", box.yMin, box.yMax);
#endif

    for (i = 0; i < box.yMax - glyph->bitmap_top; i++) {
        fputs("\tDW `", stdout);
        for (j = box.xMin; j < box.xMax; j++)
            putchar('0');
        putchar('\n');
    }
    for (i = 0; i < (FT_Int)bitmap->rows; i++) {
        fputs("\tDW `", stdout);
        for (j = box.xMin; j < glyph->bitmap_left; j++)
            putchar('0');
        for (j = 0; j < (FT_Int)bitmap->width; j++)
            putchar(bitmap->buffer[i * bitmap->width + j] ? '3' : '0');
        for (j = box.xMin + glyph->bitmap_left + bitmap->width; j < box.xMax; j++)
            putchar('0');
        putchar('\n');
    }
    for (i = box.yMin; i < glyph->bitmap_top - (FT_Int)bitmap->rows; i++) {
        fputs("\tDW `", stdout);
        for (j = box.xMin; j < box.xMax; j++)
            putchar('0');
        putchar('\n');
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

`Makefile`:

```
#########################################################################
# Copyright © 2020 James Larrowe                    #
#                                   #
# This file is part of ttf2gb.                      #
#                                   #
# ttf2gb is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify    #
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  #
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or #
# (at your option) any later version.                   #
#                                   #
# ttf2gb is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,     #
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of    #
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the     #
# GNU General Public License for more details.              #
#                                   #
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License #
# along with ttf2gb.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  #
#########################################################################
.POSIX:

# variables to be set by the user
CC = gcc
CFLAGS =
LDFLAGS =
PKG_CONFIG = pkg-config

# variables to be set by the maintainer
BUILD = RELEASE
DEBUG_OPTFLAGS = -g3
RELEASE_OPTFLAGS = -O3 -DNDEBUG
WARNFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -std=c89 -pedantic
FT_CFLAGS = `$(PKG_CONFIG) --cflags freetype2`
FT_LDFLAGS = `$(PKG_CONFIG) --libs freetype2`
REAL_CFLAGS = $($(BUILD)_OPTFLAGS) $(WARNFLAGS) $(FT_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
REAL_LDFLAGS = $(REAL_CFLAGS) $(FT_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

OBJ = main.o utils.o drawtile.o

ttf2gb: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(REAL_LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(REAL_CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f ttf2gb $(OBJ)
```

`ttf2gb.h`:

```
/*
 * Copyright © 2020 James Larrowe
 *
 * This file is part of ttf2gb.
 *
 * ttf2gb is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * ttf2gb is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with ttf2gb.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 */

#ifndef TTF2GB_H_
#define TTF2GB_H_ 1

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_TYPES_H /* FT_Error */
#include FT_FREETYPE_H /* FT_FaceRec */

/* utils.c */
/* a strerror that works on FT_Error instead of errno */
const char *ftstrerror(FT_Error error);
/* a perror for an FT_Error */
void ftperror(const char *message, FT_Error error);

/* drawtile.c */
/* draw a tile to STDOUT as RGBDS-formatted assembly */
void draw_tile(const FT_FaceRec *face);

#endif
```

`utils.c`:

```
/*
 * Copyright © 2020 James Larrowe
 *
 * This file is part of ttf2gb.
 *
 * ttf2gb is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * ttf2gb is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with ttf2gb.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 */

#include "ttf2gb.h"

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_TYPES_H

const char *ftstrerror(FT_Error error)
{
#undef FTERRORS_H_
#define FT_ERRORDEF(error_code, value, string) case error_code: return string;
#define FT_ERROR_START_LIST switch(error) {
#define FT_ERROR_END_LIST default: return "Unknown error"; }
#include FT_ERRORS_H
}

void ftperror(const char *message, FT_Error error)
{
    if(message)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", message, ftstrerror(error));
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", ftstrerror(error));
}
```

(Yes, I'm aware that this is now licensed under the CC-by-SA 4.0. Feel free to use it under that license, too.)

What I'm looking for:

- Is there a more "central" location that I can grab the dimensions from? I feel like I'm missing something, because I have to get them from the bounding box, the bitmap, and the glyph...
- Is this good usage of the FreeType library? Can anything be simplified with respect to library functions and structures?
- Are there any obscure edge cases I might've missed? This seems to generate correct results for the font I was trying to use but I didn't try it with any other fonts.
- Any other general recommendations or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does code use `FT_Int i ... for (i = 0; i < (FT_Int)bitmap->rows; i++) {` vs the type that matches `bitmap->rows`?  Curious that `for (j = box.xMin; j < glyph->bitmap_left; j++)` employs no similar cast.

Comment: @chux The types of `rows` and `bitmap_left` are different. `rows` is unsigned and `bitmap_left` is signed. I figured giving myself a signed counter would make it the easiest for me if I ever needed vertical fonts.